# Load DynaTree Dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, dynatree

I have a dynatree which I want to load the tree data dynamically. I am using this in conjunction with the jquery accordion. I'm using a for each loop to populate div's but this will be better for illustartion. Here are my divs

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Project Type</h3>
     <div id="1" class="common" style="height:150px;"> 
    </div>

     <h3>Ammenities</h3>
    <div id="2" class="common" style="height:150px;">  
    </div>
</div
```

I want to pass the id of div to the initajax function of the tree. I am getting the ID like this.

```
        $(".common").prev('h3').click(function () {
          currentID = $(this).next().attr("id");
```

I would like to pass currentID to this function

```
 var URL = "/Home/GetProjectTypeData/?currentID"
$(".common").dynatree({
    checkbox: true,
    icon: false,      
    initAjax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: URL + '=' + currentID,
        data: {},
    },
```

I've tried a couple different things, with no luck. Ideally I want each div to be populated with the tree view on click of the accordion header
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the **GetProjectTypeData** action takes a parameter called **id** then this should work:

```
$(".common").prev('h3').click(function() {

    var $tree = $(this).next('.common');

    var currentId = $tree.attr("id");

    $tree.dynatree({
        checkbox: true,
        icon: false,
        initAjax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/GetProjectTypeData',
            data: { id : currentId }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you might be on to something here, but this doesn't work. The problem I've been having is, `GetProjectTypeData()` gets called multiple times, but the parameter never changes. It seems like the initAjax call, is only called once on load

Comment: Your original code was calling dynatree many times for each click because of the selector before the dynatree call: $(".common").dynatree. The snippet that I've added only calls it once: $tree.dynatree

Comment: I am expecting dynatree to be called multiple times because my divs are generated dynamically using a for each loop. Those are just divs to illustrate for simplcity.

Comment: I have tried wrapping the dynatree call inside a function and calling it in my click event to no avail

Comment: Have you tried just pasting my code as is and trying it? If so, what error are you getting?

Comment: I thought I did before, but I tried it again and it is working. Now the div's start off expanded with no data, and the first div is acting weird and just moves up and down. lol this has not been a fun project. Going to look at it more tomorrow. Much appreciated with the help